# Noticeable Flex 3 performance increase using Canvas vs VBox/HBox?

Tags: apache-flex, performance, canvas

I was told that there is an increase in performance when using Canvas versus HBox or VBox when laying out out the position of children. As a result, a number of our components have been converted over to using Canvas. However, now there is code being added to calculate the x and y positioning of some of the child elements based off of the width and height of other children. Is it worth using a Canvas to increase performance if code needs to be added to determine the coordinates/positions of the children? Is there a better method or technique available that should be practiced other than just minimizing the number of ui components added and specifying positioning absolutely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of middle-of-the-road techniques, one of which is to use rendering-type components, such as `TileGrid` or `ItemRenderers`, if your layout fits a certain formula. If you're using forms, try using the `Form` layout component instead of using a custom layout.

If you do need to use the layout engine in Flex, the way to optimize your usage is to remember that certain techniques are used by the framework in increasing performance load, loosely following the below list, the last being the most performance intensive:

1. absolute positioning (`<Canvas>`)
2. relative positioning (`<VBox>`)
3. constraint-based positioning (`right=0`)
4. advanced constraint-based positioning (`<constraintColumns>`)

Using relative positioning is usually not that performance intensive. If you are finding that it is, it could be that you're using too many nested containers. Look at your layout architecture and try to find out ways in which your objects may be "over-laid out", and simplify them. A good tool for this is FlexSpy, which lets you introspect object layout at runtime.

Another common performance bottleneck is that your application is attempting to do some number-crunching at the exact same time that your GUI is attempting to respond to user interaction. Although no green threading frameworks exist at the moment which enable you to run UI and logic in separate 'threads', you can use a good architectural framework such as Cairngorm or Mate (there are many) which uses Commands instead of straight up methods, so that functionality execution which may take up processing cycles waits until the UI has finished responding to the user.

Answer (score 2):

A couple things you want to keep in mind while optimizing a Flex UI:

1. Avoiding excessive nesting of containers. Consider using a Canvas with absolute or constraint-based positioning over nesting lots of HBox / VBox elements. However this doesn't mean you should NEVER use VBox/HBox. You can mix and match, such as using a Canvas as the main container and positioning child Boxes inside them as needed, just try to avoid too much nesting.
2. Using the UIComponent model properly in custom components. In particular, using invalidateProperties(), invalidateSize() and invalidateDisplayList() so that their companion functions (commitProperties(), measure() and updateDisplayList()) are invoked at an optimal time for the Flash Player. Deepa gives a great talk about this here:

http://tv.adobe.com/#vi+f15384v1002

She explains how making heavy use of the invalidation scheme allows the Flash Player to execute your code at an ideal time, i.e. not in the middle of a screen update.  These principles are used by all Flex components and can/should be leveraged regardless of the framework being used.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure I understand:

- You heard that Canvas can position children faster than [VH]Box
- Canvas only does absolute positioning
- Some (many?) of your components have an absolute position, so you switched to using Canvas
- But some of your components have a relative position, so you need to write code to position them

Is that correct?

Anyway, assuming I'm correct (which may not be the case), the first thing you want to do is pick the functioning interface which requires the fewest lines of code, then decide if it's "good enough".  You want the one with the fewest lines of code because studies have shown that there is a correlation between lines of code and number of bugs (and you don't want bugs). You want to see if it's "good enough" because, if it IS "good enough", you don't need to do anything (if you *do* try and make it faster, you're committing [Premature Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)).

But that's probably not what you wanted to hear :)

So I'll also suggest that, if you want to stick with Canvas-based layout, you try sticking all the relatively positioned content inside [VH]Boxes, which are then absolutely positioned inside the Canvas.  There's a good chance the code Adobe has written is faster than code, so you should try to take advantage of it.

But the only way to know for sure is to try it and *profile it*.